# JIRA MS excel integration support or group modification

Tags: excel, tfs, jira

Using Atlassian JIRA product for first time, coming from TFS background I am missing a feature in JIRA:

During sprint planning, we normally carry forward a few sprint 1 tasks to sprint 2. Using TFS, I used to export the task list in Excel, then change the version and publish. That will change the version or other modifications for all tasks. How can I achieve that in JIRA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, it can be achieved through Bulk Change in JIRA, see steps below:

1. Go to planning board (the Bulk change operation may be available in other boards).
2. Go to Tools > Bulk Change.
3. Follow the simple steps for Bulk Change workflow.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: i first time heard this name JIRA. what it is ? will u plzz explain. thanks